# How to get autocomplete for files in subdirectories (discord.js-commando)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, autocomplete, discord.js

Visual Studio properly autocompletes code for everything within the index.js file.

For example, if I type `msg.member.`, VS shows me the properties/methods related to GuildMember.

However, for the command files in .\commands\group, VS does not autocomplete things related to discord.js-commando. If I use mysql, it autocompletes that. For example, I have the following code:

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

When I type `mysql.`, VS shows me a bunch of functions I can call. However, it does not autocomplete stuff related to discord.js-commando. For example, I have some sample code again (continued from the first two lines)

```
module.exports = class nameCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'name',
            group: 'group',
            memberName: 'mName',
            description: 'desc'
        });
    }

    run(msg) {
       
    }
};
```

In the `run(msg)` function, when I hover over `msg`, VS shows me **msg: any**. Within the function, if I type `msg.member.`, VS does not provide any autocomplete suggestions.

TL;DR: VS autocompletes everything not related to discord.js-commando for command files (located in subdirectories) but autocompletes properly for the index.js file in the main directory.

What's going on, and how do I get autocomplete for the command files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's very simple, you just need to add, the [JSdocs](https://jsdoc.app/) you need to add the [@param](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) tag, and to assign `msg` to the param, you just need to do;

```js
const { Command, CommandoMessage } = require('discord.js-commando');
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

In the top of your message and after that, you just simply do:

```js
module.exports = class nameCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
      super(client, {
          name: 'name',
          group: 'group',
          memberName: 'mName',
          description: 'desc'
      });
  }
  /**
   * @param {CommandoMessage} msg 
   */
  run(msg) {
     
  }
};
```

That's all, like I said, it's very simple you just need to add this in all your files, and get `CommandoMessage`